# Склонение в moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, локализация, momentjs

В momentjs есть такая фича, что можно склонять дни. Например, 1 день, 2 дня, 5 дней. Но вот как это сделать - я без понятия. Обыскался уже в документации. Может знает кто?

Answer (score 8):

Может кому поможет. Также возникла проблема со склонением месяца.

```
date.format('YYYY MMMM D') // месяц - март
date.format('D MMMM') // выводит - марта
```

логика библиотеки следующая:

```
var MONTHS_IN_FORMAT = /D[oD]?(\[[^\[\]]*\]|\s)+MMMM?/;
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот код этой функции. Но её экспортировать нельзя, она локальная.
https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/locale/ru.js#L15

Это простая функция. Просто скопируйте эту или возьмите из npm любую по запросу russian pluralize.

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. В итоге в [документации](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/) нашел как можно реализовать

```
moment().from(moment().subtract(4, 'days'), true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
moment.duration(day, 'day').locale('ru').humanize()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]